# Geoserver CSS plugin - combining styles

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, css

I'm currently trying to write some SLD styles using the CSS plugin in geoserver. The problem is that the plugin merges single rules into complexed ones, ie. the following code generates 5 rules instead of 3 and the layer isn't rendering correctly. It all works ok when I use only one type of key, like define styles only for boundary or only for highway.
I've found [THIS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/metadata.html), but I don't know how to understand it. Any ideas? Please help.

```
[highway = 'primary'][@scale<4000000]{
 stroke: black;
  width: 1px;
}

[boundary = 'administrative'] [admin_level = 2]{
    stroke: #B19AC2;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

[boundary = 'administrative'] [admin_level = 4]{
    stroke: #B19AC2;
  stroke-width: 1px;
     stroke-dasharray: 3 2;
}
```

gives this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">3.0 2.0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MinScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">3.0 2.0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>admin_level</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>boundary</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>administrative</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>primary</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>4000000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#B19AC2</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">3.0 2.0</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: can you try to clarify your question - are you trying to style roads or admin boundaries? What isn't right about the output you get?

Comment: Let's say I'm trying to display on the layer three different things at the same time - country boundaries, county boundaries and primary highways. When I delete the style rule for primary highways, it works ok, the boundaries are displayed. Together with highway style the're not working. Look at the SLD output, imho it does not correspond to the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style two unrelated things then you need two styles - one for highways and one for admin lines. Otherwise you will end up with complex SLDs with many rules that can never be true (i.e. 'highway' = 'primary' && admin_level = 2).

Comment: There is a way to `include` one css inside other by using reference or I need to redeclare everything in both files?

Comment: what everything? there shouldn't be any overlap

Comment: I mean if I have a complex line style in one css file and I need to use same line style as a border in other style or something like that. Like reusing complex base styles to compose others.

Comment: But how to style one layer containing different types of features like highways and admin lines with multiple styles? AFAIK, there should be one sld for each layer. I don't even know how to set different style files for one layer in geoserver.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I can choose multiple styles for layer in Geoserver under the "Publishing" tab, in Properties of a layer. Am I right?

Comment: So I found out that I can't use multpile sld files to style a single layer at the same time.