# Why is my geoserver css style not working when I add multiple filters?

Tags: geoserver, style, css

I am using Geoserver and the CSS Style plugin. The following code works fine and shows an 'L' when the feature is 'Left' and the '*' filter catches anything else and shows it as an X.

```
* {
 mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02');
 mark-size: 24;
}

[left_right = 'Left'] {
  mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C');
  mark-size: 18;
}
```

However, when I add a filter for 'Right' then 'R' and 'L' show up but then the catch-all `*` filter stops working.

```
* {
 mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02');
 mark-size: 24;
}

[left_right = 'Left'] {
  mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C');
  mark-size: 18;
}

[left_right = 'Right'] {
  mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x0052');
  mark-size: 18;
}
```

I have changed the `*` rule to the lines below and the symbol still doesn't show up.

```
[left_right <> 'Right'] [left_right <> 'Left']
[left_right <> 'Right' or left_right <> 'Left']
[left_right = '']
```

I have also left the `*` filter alone and added `[left_right = '']` as a fourth filter and it doesn't show up either.

I guess I am missing a basic concept of styling rules but I can't figure out what it is. It looks simple to me - I should be able to change my symbol based on the feature attribute. I am not [symbolizing unrelated things](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198174/17879) so I don't see why I would need separate styles.

I have not tried changing the [@mode rules](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/cascading.html#understanding-css-to-sld-translation-in-cascading-mode) since I do not think this should generate an overly complicated SLD style.

What can I change or am I doing wrong?

Full version of the code minus the filter for 'Right':

```
* {
 mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02');
 mark-size: 24;
}

[left_right = 'Left'] {
  mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C');
  mark-size: 18;
}

:symbol {
 fill: black;
}


[@scale > 2500] {
  mark-size: 6;
}
```

Comment: What are the other values besides "Left" and "Right"? Did you check the generated SLD?

Comment: I'll update the question with the full code. I have reviewed the SLD but didn't meticulously go through it hoping for someone more experienced to know the answer offhand. I'll look through it more in-depth.

Comment: @AndreaAime Perhaps you weren't asking for the other values of the code but what are other attributes for that field. The other values are: 24"", 33"", 35"", ?,left, and empty lines. These are errors but for now they are in there.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the generated SLD on GeoServer 2.9.1 but I cannot see an evident misbehavior. 
The full style cited at the end of your response, that is,

```
* {
 mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02');
 mark-size: 24;
}

[left_right = 'Left'] {
  mark: symbol('ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C');
  mark-size: 18;
}

:symbol {
 fill: black;
}


[@scale > 2500] {
  mark-size: 6;
}
```

Generates the rules I would expect, that i:

- Left and scale < 2500
- Left and scale > 2500
- Not Left and scale < 2500
- Not left and scale > 2500

In SLD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
      <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
          <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
          <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <sld:Rule>
              <ogc:Filter>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>left_right</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Left</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
              <sld:MinScaleDenominator>2500.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
              <sld:PointSymbolizer>
                <sld:Graphic>
                  <sld:Mark>
                    <sld:WellKnownName>ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C</sld:WellKnownName>
                    <sld:Fill>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                  </sld:Mark>
                  <sld:Size>6</sld:Size>
                </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:PointSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
            <sld:Rule>
              <ogc:Filter>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>left_right</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Left</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
              <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2500.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
              <sld:PointSymbolizer>
                <sld:Graphic>
                  <sld:Mark>
                    <sld:WellKnownName>ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x004C</sld:WellKnownName>
                    <sld:Fill>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                  </sld:Mark>
                  <sld:Size>18</sld:Size>
                </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:PointSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
            <sld:Rule>
              <ogc:Filter>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>left_right</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Left</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
              <sld:MinScaleDenominator>2500.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
              <sld:PointSymbolizer>
                <sld:Graphic>
                  <sld:Mark>
                    <sld:WellKnownName>ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02</sld:WellKnownName>
                    <sld:Fill>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                  </sld:Mark>
                  <sld:Size>6</sld:Size>
                </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:PointSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
            <sld:Rule>
              <ogc:Filter>
                <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>left_right</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Left</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
              <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>2500.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
              <sld:PointSymbolizer>
                <sld:Graphic>
                  <sld:Mark>
                    <sld:WellKnownName>ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2A02</sld:WellKnownName>
                    <sld:Fill>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Fill>
                  </sld:Mark>
                  <sld:Size>24</sld:Size>
                </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:PointSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
            <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
          </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
      </sld:NamedLayer>
    </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

A version with also right also generates the 6 rules I would expect:

- Left and scale < 2500
- Left and scale > 2500
- Right and scale > 2500
- Right and scale < 2500
- Not Left and Not Right and scale < 2500
- Not Left and Not right and scale < 2500

Comment: Hey. I've come up with the same rules which seems to rule out a CSS Plugin issue and now its more a geoserver SLD issue? Nonetheless, it still stand that the * features don't display. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That would be a new issue... if you have a sample data set, style, and WMS request that makes it happen, open a ticket and add such information: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary
I don't believe progress can be made without actually looking at the data at this point